# jquery show/hide div after already showing a div from a dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So i using a modal, than when loaded, the first select option shows two divs. I got that to function properly, but now i want it to show specific divs based on the third dropdown. Basically, they are choosing one of two options from the top. depending on what those are it displays two more drop downs. they choose the second one, and than depending on what they do for the third dropdown, it will display the next bit of divs. But no matter where or how i place to pull the value and declare it, its not responding, nor showing the next set of divs. Heres the code :

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-body">
    <center>Owner Controls</strong>
    <hr>
    <?php echo form_open(base_url('admin/work/owner_control'), 'class="form-container"'); ?>

    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="chng_fun">Mine or Refinery:</label>
                <select id="chng_fun" name="chng_fun" class="browser-default custom-select custom-select-lg mb-3">
                    <option value="" selected>Please select</option>
          <option value="mine">Mines</option>
          <option value="refinery">Refineries</option>
          </select>
            <span id="chng_funx" class="errx"></span>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="minesli" style="display:none">
            <label for="mineslist">Select Mine:</label>
                <select id="mineslist" name="mineslist" class="browser-default custom-select custom-select-lg mb-3">
                    <option value="" selected>Please select </option>
                    <?php foreach($mineat as $minev){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $minev['mi_id'];?>"><?php echo $minev['mname'];?></option>
            <?php } ?>                           
                    </select>
            <span id="mineslistx" class="errx"></span>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="refineli" style="display:none">
            <label for="refinelist">Select Refinery:</label>
                <select id="refinelist" name="mineslist" class="browser-default custom-select custom-select-lg mb-3">
                    <option value="" selected>Please select </option>
                    <?php foreach($refneat as $refv){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $refv['ref_id'];?>"><?php echo $refv['rename'];?></option>
            <?php } ?>                           
                    </select>
            <span id="refinelistx" class="errx"></span>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="moption" style="display:none">
            <label for="moptionsl">Pick Mine Option:</label>
                <select id="moptionsl" name="moptionsl" class="browser-default custom-select custom-select-lg mb-3">
                    <option value="" selected>Please select </option>
          <option value="upgrade">Upgrade</option>
          <option value="sell" disabled>Sell</option>
          <option value="taxes">Taxes</option>
          <option value="destroy">Destroy</option>
                
                    </select>
            <span id="moptionslx" class="errx"></span>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="roption" style="display:none">
            <label for="roptionsl">Pick Refinery Option:</label>
                <select id="roptionsl" name="roptionsl" class="browser-default custom-select custom-select-lg mb-3">
                    <option value="" selected>Please select </option>
          <option value="upgrade">Upgrade</option>
          <option value="sell" disabled>Sell</option>
          <option value="taxes">Taxes</option>
          <option value="destroy">Destroy</option>
                
                    </select>
            <span id="roptionslx" class="errx"></span>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="minupgrade" style="display:none">
    
   <center> FREAKING WORK!</center>
                                                
            <span id="muppgradex" class="errx"></span>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="refupgrade" style="display:none">

    ROCK ON

            <span id="ruppgradex" class="errx"></span>
        </div>

    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So basically what im trying to pull is the value from moptions1 and roptions1, declare them, and than display minupgrade div if moptions1 is upgrade, and refupgrade div if roptions1 is upgrade. Heres the Javascript:

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}


// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
   
   
   $("#chng_fun").change(function(){      
     var action  = $("#chng_fun").val();



     if(action == "mine"){
      $('#minesli').show('slow');
      $('#moption').show('slow');
        }else{
      $('#minesli').hide('slow');
      $('#moption').hide('slow');
    }

    var choice = $('#moptions1').val();

    if(choice == "upgrade"){
      $('#minupgrade').show('slow');
        }else{
      $('#minupgrade').hide('slow');
    }

    if(action == "refinery"){
      $('#refineli').show('slow');
      $('#roption').show('slow');
        }else{
      $('#refineli').hide('slow');
      $('#roption').hide('slow');
    }
    var choice2 = $('#roptions1').val();

    if(choice2 == "upgrade"){
      $('#refupgrade').show('slow');
        }else{
      $('#refupgrade').hide('slow');
    }

  });


});
     
</script>
```

I have tried moving variables around, i also tried using a if (action == "mine" && choice == "upgrade") in both itself and inside the action == "mine" as an if else. Ive trie dmoving the var and portion of the code to various places to see if it responds better, but no matter what ive tried its not capturing the value and displaying the divs.

Comment: Hi there are typos in your code i.e : this `$('#moptions1').val();` should be `$('#moptionsl').val();` and `$('#roptions1').val();` should be `$('#roptionsl').val();` .Also change your event selector to `$(".modal  select").change(function() {` so that it gets called whenever any select-box is change inside modal.

Comment: Awesome, seems to be working good now. Thank you! minor mistakes on my part and still learning DOM manipulation.